# Responding to multiple matches in Chatscript

Tags: nlp, chat, chatscript

I am currently trying to learn Chatscript but the documentation seems to be poor. My current issue is how to respond to a multi-statement match to input. So, if I say "Hi. Tell me about yourself" and I have a match for "hi" and "about yourself" it will respond to the first match and not the last. I'm pretty sure I need the control script to change to fix this but am not sure which commands to use. Maybe something that stores all matches in last input and can pick a specific one?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a u: response that uses ^next & refine() to move through the sentences starting with something like ~greeting. This is **pseudo code**:

```
u: ( ~greeting ) 

   ^refine()

 a: ( %more ) 

    ^next(input) 
    ^refine()

    b: ( you be ? )

       I'm good!

    b: ( %lenght==0 ) 

       Hi!
```

([ChatScript System Functions Manual](https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/blob/master/WIKI/ChatScript-System-Functions-Manual.md#next--what-label-))

> ^next(what label) – given what of GAMBIT or RESPONDER or REJOINDER or 
>   RULE and a rule label or tag, find the next rule of that what. Fails if none is found. 
>   REJOINDER will fail if it reaches the next top level rule. If label is “~”, it will use the 
>   last call's answer as the starting point, enabling you to walk rules in succession. There is 
>   also ^next(FACT @xxx) – see fact manual. **For ^next(input) the system will read the 
>   next sentence and prep the system with it. This means that all patterns and code executing
>   thereafter will be in the context of the next input sentence.** That sentence is now used up, 
>   and will not be seen next when the current revised sentence finishes.